# How to copy files of an extension, only if the same file exist in the destination?

Tags: scripts, files, clipboard

It may sound strange, but I really want to copy only the **existing** files, so this files will be updated/overridden, and any new file will not be added.

I want to copy files of a single extension. It works well with this script line:

```
rsync -avm --include='*.bak' -f 'hide,! */' /Directory-to-be-backed-up/ /media/USB_stick
```

But I also want that the file to be copied only if it already exist in the destiny (overriding it).

For example, I have this 3 files in `/tmp/a`:

```
/tmp/a/1.h
/tmp/a/2.h
/tmp/a/internal/3.h
```

And this 2 files in `/tmp/b`:

```
/tmp/b/1.h
/tmp/b/internal/3.h
```

I would like to update/override the **existing files** in `/tmp/b` using the ones in `/tmp/a`, but not copy any new file (like the `/tmp/a/2.h`).

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd reorder your command a bit, first I'd remove the `--include` and instead just put the `*.bak` right into the source path. Next you can add [`--existing`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to copy only existing files.

One possible way to do it (not tested):

```
rsync -avm --existing /Directory-to-be-backed-up/*.bak /media/USB_stick
```

Comment: I was going to suggest rsync ;)